# BF interpreter written in C#

Tags: c#, interpreter, brainfuck

I have recently written a Brainfuck interpreter in C#. I tested it with the examples given on EsoLang website. It does not handle errors right now.

Questions:

1. Even that it can run only one program at once, should I maybe put the variables into the class (create new class) or just leave them inside the `BF` method?
2. Should I split all of the code from the cases and create separate methods for them, accessing them from the `switch`?

Of course, I am also looking for all other suggestions on how I can improve this code.

```
using System;

namespace BF
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Specify the source file!");
            } else {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(args[0]) == true) {
                    BF(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[0]).ToCharArray());
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("The path to the file is not valid!");
                }
            }


        }

        private static void BF(char[] instructions)
        {
            int instructionPointer = 0;

            int[] memory = new int[30000];

            int pointer = 1;

            while (instructionPointer < instructions.Length) {

                switch (instructions[instructionPointer]) {

                    case '>': {
                            pointer += 1;
                            break;
                        }

                    case '<': {
                            pointer -= 1;
                            break;
                        }

                    case '+': {
                            memory[pointer] += 1;
                            break;
                        }

                    case '-': {
                            memory[pointer] -= 1;
                            break;
                        }

                    case '.': {
                            Console.Write((char)memory[pointer]);
                            break;
                        }

                    case ',': {
                            memory[pointer] = byte.Parse(Console.Read().ToString());
                            break;
                        }
                    case '[':
                        {
                        if (memory[pointer] == 0) {
                            int s = 0;
                            int ptr = instructionPointer + 1;
                            while (instructions[ptr] != ']' || s > 0) {
                                if (instructions[ptr] == '[') {
                                    s += 1;
                                } else if (instructions[ptr] == ']') {
                                    s -= 1;
                                }
                                ptr += 1;
                                instructionPointer = ptr;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }

                    case ']': {
                            if (memory[pointer] != 0) {
                                int s = 0;
                                int ptr = instructionPointer - 1;
                                while (instructions[ptr] != '[' || s > 0) {
                                    if (instructions[ptr] == ']') {
                                        s += 1;
                                    } else if (instructions[ptr] == '[') {
                                        s -= 1;
                                    }
                                    ptr -= 1;
                                    instructionPointer = ptr;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                }


                instructionPointer += 1;

            }




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to CodeReview! Hope you get some nice reviews.

Comment: You can stack switch conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> int pointer = 1;
> ```

Looks like you're throwing away `memory[0]` here; I'd expect the `pointer` to initialize at the very start of the "tape".

---

> ```
> if (System.IO.File.Exists(args[0]) == true)
> ```

The `== true` part is redundant, and the fully-qualified `File.Exists` feels... crowded. I'd remove `System.IO.` and add `using System.IO;` at the top of the file.

Arguably if no argument is specified, you should be throwing some `ArgumentException` instead of just saying "specify the source file" and exiting with a code-0, which would be interpreted as a successful run. Such a guard clause would help reduce nesting in the `Main` procedure:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No source file was specified.");
        }
        if (!File.Exists(args[0]))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Specified source file was not found.");
        }

        BF(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[0]).ToCharArray());
    }
```

Notice the consistency with brace positioning; your code alternates between C#-style and Java-style braces, depending on whether we're looking at a member or its body - it really doesn't matter which one you prefer, but pick a style, and stick to it.

---

"BF" might perhaps possibly make a [bad] class name - it's a *noun*. But here `BF` is a *method*, and methods *do something*, they're *verbs*. `Interpret` or even `Run` would be a better choice.

---

BF is a simple language; you don't need to go out of your way and implement a *lexer* to *tokenize* input and a *parser* to make sense out of it - basically every single character is an *instruction*, so it makes sense to process it one character at a time.

But is it ideal to read an entire file's contents, iterate every single character to create a character array, and then pass that array to a method that will iterate it one item at a time? Seems rather inefficient, considering you could be *streaming* the file content into the interpreter, and finish interpreting the BF program as you finish reading the last character in the file, having iterated the contents exactly once.

---

I think I'd make a separate dedicated class for the interpreter, with the `pointer` and `memory[]` as instance fields; I'd make a `Dictionary<char, Action>` to map each BF token to a dedicated method, too.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice this `int pointer = 1;`.

Comment: A counter argument against streaming the code is that BF programs can have loops, so you have to keep most of the code in memory anyway.

Comment: @RolandIllig wouldn't only the loop body need to stick around though? I've never written a BF interpreter, ...your comment makes me want to give it a shot :-)

Comment: The code from the question is the most straight-forward way to write a BF interpreter. When you want to discard code from memory, you can only do if after proving that it is dead code. This will make the interpreter so much more complicated that it is usually not done. You would need the typical data flow analysis algorithms for this task.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: You should really write your own BF interpreter, it's a matter of a few hours only. When you are finished, you could review your answer here and check whether using a `Dictionary` and separate methods really make the code clearer. I doubt so, since almost every simple BF interpreter is just the basic `while switch` loop. This coding style makes stepping through the code really simple, unlike having to deal with separate methods (unless, maybe, for the `[` and `]` commands).

Comment: Look at you. It's almost like you know a few things about compilers or something.

Comment: @RubberDuck lol, I started making one in C# 6, got the lexer done, hoping to finish the parser and the interpreter tonight. Not the "simple BF interpreter", but the work will be useful for RD's 2.x syntax trees :-)

Comment: @RolandIllig how about an [instruction per class](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145060/23788)? I have to say it was pretty fun to implement.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace BF
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Specify the source file!");
```

(Functionality) Since the above is an error message, it should be written using `Console.Error.WriteLine`. Additionally, you should call `Environment.Exit(1);` to tell the calling program about the usage error.

```
            } else {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(args[0]) == true) {
```

(Style) You can omit the `== true`.

```
                    BF(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[0]).ToCharArray());
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("The path to the file is not valid!");
                }
            }


        }
```

(Style) Why do you have two empty lines between the above closing braces? Usually, one empty line is enough, and in this case, I would prefer to have zero empty lines.

```
        private static void BF(char[] instructions)
        {
            int instructionPointer = 0;

            int[] memory = new int[30000];

            int pointer = 1;
```

(Functionality) You should initialize `pointer = 0`, since the first valid index for a C# array is `0`.

```
            while (instructionPointer < instructions.Length) {

                switch (instructions[instructionPointer]) {

                    case '>': {
                            pointer += 1;
```

(Style) Instead of `pointer += 1`, it is more common to write `pointer++`.

```
                            break;
                        }

                    case '<': {
                            pointer -= 1;
```

(Style) This one should be `pointer--`.

```
                            break;
                        }

                    case '+': {
                            memory[pointer] += 1;
                            break;
                        }
```

(Style) As long as you don't declare any local variables, the braces in each of the `case`s are not necessary. A `case` statement takes quite a lot of screen space because of all the `break` statements, so enclosing them in braces wastes even more space.

```
                    case '-': {
                            memory[pointer] -= 1;
                            break;
                        }

                    case '.': {
                            Console.Write((char)memory[pointer]);
```

(Functionality) Using three different types for the `memory` cells makes the Brainfuck programs hard to debug. You use `int` for the loops, `char` when writing a character and `byte` when reading a character. This is very confusing. Choose one of the types and use it in all places.

```
                            break;
                        }

                    case ',': {
                            memory[pointer] = byte.Parse(Console.Read().ToString());
```

(Functionality) It is simpler to just say `memory[pointer] = (byte) Console.Read()`. Or just leave out the type cast and simply say `memory[pointer] = Console.Read()`.

```
                            break;
                        }
                    case '[':
                        {
                        if (memory[pointer] == 0) {
                            int s = 0;
                            int ptr = instructionPointer + 1;
                            while (instructions[ptr] != ']' || s > 0) {
                                if (instructions[ptr] == '[') {
                                    s += 1;
                                } else if (instructions[ptr] == ']') {
                                    s -= 1;
                                }
                                ptr += 1;
                                instructionPointer = ptr;
                                }
```

(Style) The closing brace is indented at the same level as the statements above it. This looks wrong.

```
                            }
                            break;
                        }

                    case ']': {
                            if (memory[pointer] != 0) {
                                int s = 0;
```

(Style) Why did you call this variable `s`? I would understand `level`, `depth` or some similar name, but `s` is usually a name for a `string`.

```
                                int ptr = instructionPointer - 1;
                                while (instructions[ptr] != '[' || s > 0) {
                                    if (instructions[ptr] == ']') {
                                        s += 1;
                                    } else if (instructions[ptr] == '[') {
                                        s -= 1;
                                    }
                                    ptr -= 1;
                                    instructionPointer = ptr;
                                }
```

(Functionality) If the brainfuck program has unbalanced loop brackets, your code will throw an exception because `ptr` will be outside the valid range for the `memory` index. You have to choose whether you want to add error handling code here.

```
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                }


                instructionPointer += 1;

            }




        }
    }
}
```

(Style) The many empty lines look unorganized. Just remove them, unless you want to organize your code into paragraphs for human readers. Then use one empty line for that.

Overall: The code is easy to read and nicely structured. There are only some small stylistic things and some bits around error handling that could be improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll load the file to an char array as you suggested.

Comment: Very nice review here, many nice catches, keep 'em coming! IMO `s` is just a bad name though ;-)

Comment: Yeah that wasn't a nice name, I did it by an accident as my native language is Polish. `s` stands for Stopień here.