# Object-oriented Brainfuck interpreter

Tags: c#, interpreter, brainfuck

Inspired by [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144835/bf-interpreter-written-in-c), I decided to give it a try and implemented a brainfuck interpreter myself. It includes various improvements:

- It's object-oriented and modular
- Unlimited tape size
- It includes a call stack (no seeking for opening parenthesis)
- It allows stepping and debugging
- It throws exceptions on errors

### Tape

```
/// <summary>
/// One-sided, infinite, default-initialized Tape. </summary>
public class Tape<T>
{
    List<T> _tape;
    int _pos;

    public Tape()
    {
        _tape = new List<T>();
        _tape.Add(default(T));
        _pos = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Currently selected cell's value. </summary>
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _tape[_pos];
        }
        set
        {
            _tape[_pos] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Step one cell to the left. </summary>
    public void StepLeft()
    {
        if (_pos == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        else
            _pos--;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Step one cell to the right. </summary>
    public void StepRight()
    {
        _pos++;
        if (_pos == _tape.Count)
            _tape.Add(default(T));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a full snapshot of the tape without altering anything. </summary>
    public T[] ToArray()
    {
        return _tape.ToArray();
    }
}
```

### Interpreter

```
public class BrainfuckInterpreter
{    
    Stream _program;
    Stream _input;
    Stream _output;
    Tape<byte> _tape;
    Stack<long> _callStack;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new BrainfuckInterpreter. </summary>
    /// <param name="program">
    /// Program to be executed. Must be readable and seekable.
    /// <param name="input">
    /// Must be readable. Can be null if the program doesn't take any input. </param>
    /// <param name="output">
    /// Must be writable. Can be null if the program doesn't produce output. </param>
    public BrainfuckInterpreter(Stream program, Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        _program = program;
        _input = input;
        _output = output;
        _tape = new Tape<byte>();
        _callStack = new Stack<long>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Run the program until it terminates. </summary>
    public void Run()
    {
        while (Step());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute the next command. </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// False if the program terminated. True otherwise. </returns>
    public bool Step()
    {
        int command = _program.ReadByte();
        switch (command)
        {
            default: throw new ArgumentException(); // Invalid command
            case -1: return false; // End reached
            case '+': _tape.Value++; break;
            case '-': _tape.Value--; break;
            case ',':
                int input = _input.ReadByte();
                if (input == -1) // Null-termination instead of error status
                    _tape.Value = 0;
                else
                    _tape.Value = (byte)input;
                break;
            case '.': _output.WriteByte(_tape.Value); break;
            case '>': _tape.StepRight(); break;
            case '<': _tape.StepLeft(); break;
            case '[': _callStack.Push(_program.Position); break;
            case ']':
                if (_tape.Value == 0)
                    _callStack.Pop();
                else
                    _program.Position = _callStack.Peek();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Print the tape for debug purposes.
    /// Format (hex): |XX|XX|XX|...|XX| </summary>
    public string Print()
    {
        string result = "|";
        foreach (var n in _tape.ToArray())
        {
            result += String.Format("{0:X2}|", n);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Main routine (for testing)

Takes the program directly (not a filename) as first command line argument. Prints the tape's contents to `stderr` after each step.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stream program = new MemoryStream(args[0].Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray());
        var bf = new BrainfuckInterpreter(
            program,
            Console.OpenStandardInput(),
            Console.OpenStandardOutput()
        );
        while (bf.Step())
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(bf.Print());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test your code? The program `[+[]]` should terminate quickly because the `+` is never executed, while the program `+[]` should never terminate.

Comment: @RolandIllig I hadn't read the brainfuck specification thoroughly, so my interpreter uses `do {} while()` instead of `while() {}`, as @200_success correctly determined. I indeed tested it with some self-written brainfuck, which I obviously also wrote in my "newly invented" dialect. It therefore works as expected, but it's not standard brainfuck.

Comment: For future reference: Test your interpretation implementation on [FizzBuzz in Brainfuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57382/31562) if that doesn't print FizzBuzz, you've done something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> switch (command)
> {
>     …
>     case '[': _callStack.Push(_program.Position); break;
>     case ']':
>         if (_tape.Value == 0)
>             _callStack.Pop();
>         else
>             _program.Position = _callStack.Peek();
>         break;
> }
> ```

A call stack in a tape-based language?  Heresy!

Seriously, though, the code is wrong.  You have implemented a `do { … } while (_tape.Value != 0)` loop instead of a `while (_tape.Value != 0) { … }` loop.