# A completely overkill BrainFuck lexer/parser

Tags: c#, object-oriented, parsing, brainfuck

I'll need to build a syntax tree (AST) for Rubberduck, but since VBA has dozens of tokens and complex rules, I needed a simpler language to play with first, so I thought BrainFuck would be a perfect candidate.

[image: debugger view of the parse tree]

The result is completely overkill for BF, but the exercise was very educational.

### Lexer

The lexer reads the code as a string or stream input, and yields *tokens* - a *trivia token* can *span* multiple characters, *instruction tokens* are all single-character:

```
using BrainFuck.Tokens;

namespace BrainFuck
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An object responsible for tokenizing an input stream.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class Lexer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Yields tokens from the input stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">Any stream of BrainFuck source code.</param>
        public IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize(System.IO.Stream input)
        {
            var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(input);
            var currentTokenPosition = Span.Empty;
            var currentTriviaSpan = Span.Empty;
            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            var tokenCount = 0;

            while (reader.Peek() > 0)
            {
                var current = (char) reader.Read();
                var next = (char) reader.Peek();

                if (IsNewLine(current, next))
                {
                    builder.Append(current);
                    currentTriviaSpan = currentTriviaSpan.NextLine;
                    currentTokenPosition = currentTokenPosition.NewLine;

                    if (Environment.NewLine.Length == 2)
                    {
                        current = (char) reader.Read();
                        builder.Append(current);
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                Token token;
                if (IsToken(currentTokenPosition, tokenCount, current, out token))
                {
                    // if we were building a trivia token, we need to yield it first:
                    if (builder.Length != 0)
                    {
                        yield return new TriviaToken(currentTriviaSpan, tokenCount, builder.ToString());
                        tokenCount++;
                    }

                    yield return token;
                    tokenCount++;

                    currentTriviaSpan = currentTokenPosition.Next;
                    currentTokenPosition = currentTriviaSpan.End;
                    builder.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.Append(current);
                }

                if (next != 0)
                {
                    currentTriviaSpan = currentTriviaSpan.NextColumn;
                }
            }

            if (builder.Length != 0)
            {
                currentTriviaSpan = currentTriviaSpan.PreviousColumn;
                yield return new TriviaToken(currentTriviaSpan, tokenCount, builder.ToString());
                builder.Clear();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns tokens from input string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">BrainFuck source code</param>
        public IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize(string input)
        {
            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Default);
                writer.Write(input);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

                var tokens = Tokenize(stream).ToList();
                writer.Dispose();

                return tokens;
            }
        }

        private static bool IsNewLine(char character, char next)
        {
            return new string(new[] {character, next}).Equals(Environment.NewLine)
                   || Environment.NewLine.Equals(character.ToString());
        }

        private static readonly IDictionary<string, Func<Span, int, Token>>
            TokenFactories = new Dictionary<string, Func<Span, int, Token>>
            {
                {MoveLeftToken.Token, (span, index) => new MoveLeftToken(span, index)},
                {MoveRightToken.Token, (span, index) => new MoveRightToken(span, index)},
                {BeginLoopToken.Token, (span, index) => new BeginLoopToken(span, index)},
                {EndLoopToken.Token, (span, index) => new EndLoopToken(span, index)},
                {IncrementToken.Token, (span, index) => new IncrementToken(span, index)},
                {DecrementToken.Token, (span, index) => new DecrementToken(span, index)},
                {InputToken.Token, (span, index) => new InputToken(span, index)},
                {OutputToken.Token, (span, index) => new OutputToken(span, index)},
            };

        private static bool IsToken(Span position, int index, char input, out Token token)
        {
            Func<Span, int, Token> factory;
            if (TokenFactories.TryGetValue(input.ToString(), out factory))
            {
                token = factory.Invoke(position, index);
                return true;
            }

            token = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

### Parser

The parser processes tokens and generates a parse tree.

```
using BrainFuck.Syntax;
using BrainFuck.Tokens;

namespace BrainFuck
{
    public class Parser
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<TokenType, Func<SyntaxTree>> SyntaxTrees =
            new Dictionary<TokenType, Func<SyntaxTree>>
            {
                {TokenType.Trivia, () => new TriviaSyntax()},
                {TokenType.Increment, () => new IncrementInstructionSyntax()},
                {TokenType.Decrement, () => new DecrementInstructionSyntax()},
                {TokenType.MoveLeft, () => new MoveLeftInstructionSyntax()},
                {TokenType.MoveRight, () => new MoveRightInstructionSyntax()},
                {TokenType.Input, () => new InputInstructionSyntax()},
                {TokenType.Output, () => new OutputInstructionSyntax()},
            };

        public SyntaxTree Parse(Token[] tokens)
        {
            var index = 0;
            var depth = 0;
            return Parse(tokens, ref index, ref depth);
        }

        private static SyntaxTree Parse(IReadOnlyList<Token> tokens, ref int index, ref int depth, SyntaxTree root = null)
        {
            if(root == null)
            {
                root = new SyntaxTree();
            }

            Token previousToken = null;
            SyntaxTree currentTree = null;
            SyntaxTree previousTree = null;

            while(index < tokens.Count)
            {
                var token = tokens[index];
                index++;

                Func<SyntaxTree> treeFactory;
                if(SyntaxTrees.TryGetValue(token.Type, out treeFactory))
                {
                    // trivia or instruction token
                    if(previousToken?.Type == token.Type)
                    {
                        previousTree?.Add(token);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (previousTree != null)
                        {
                            root.Add(previousTree);
                        }

                        currentTree = treeFactory.Invoke();
                        currentTree.Add(token);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // control flow token
                    if(previousTree != null)
                    {
                        root.Add(previousTree);
                    }
                    switch(token.Type)
                    {
                        case TokenType.BeginLoop:
                            depth++;
                            currentTree = Parse(tokens, ref index, ref depth, new LoopBlockSyntax { token });
                            break;

                        case TokenType.EndLoop:
                            if(depth == 0)
                            {
                                throw new IllegalTokenException(token);
                            }
                            depth--;

                            root.Add(token);
                            return root;

                        default:
                            throw new IllegalTokenException(token);
                    }
                }

                previousToken = token;
                previousTree = currentTree;
            }

            if (previousTree != null)
            {
                root.Add(previousTree);
            }
            return root;
        }
    }
}
```

### Interpreter

The interpreter traverses the parse tree and executes all instructions.

```
using BrainFuck.Syntax;

namespace BrainFuck
{
    public class Interpreter
    {
        private readonly ExecutionContext _context;

        public Interpreter(ExecutionContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Execute(SyntaxTree tree)
        {
            foreach (var instruction in tree.Children)
            {
                (instruction as IInstruction)?.Execute(_context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### LoopBlockInstruction

The loop instruction overrides the default "execute instruction once for each token" behavior:

```
using System;

namespace BrainFuck.Syntax
{
    public sealed class LoopBlockSyntax : InstructionSyntaxTree
    {
        private const int MaxIterations = short.MaxValue;

        protected override void ExecuteOnce(ExecutionContext context)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void Execute(ExecutionContext context)
        {
            var iterations = 0;
            while(context.IsTrue())
            {
                foreach (var instruction in Children)
                {
                    (instruction as IInstruction)?.Execute(context);
                }

                if (iterations == MaxIterations) { throw new InfiniteLoopException(); }
                iterations++;
            }
        }
    }

    public class InfiniteLoopException : Exception
    {
    }
}
```

#### IncrementInstructionSyntax

The other syntax tree implementations are dead simple:

```
namespace BrainFuck.Syntax
{
    public sealed class IncrementInstructionSyntax : InstructionSyntaxTree
    {
        protected override void ExecuteOnce(ExecutionContext context)
        {
            context.Increment();
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### InstructionSyntaxTree

The base class for all instructions:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace BrainFuck.Syntax
{
    public abstract class InstructionSyntaxTree : SyntaxTree, IInstruction
    {
        protected abstract void ExecuteOnce(ExecutionContext context);

        public virtual void Execute(ExecutionContext context)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once UnusedVariable; instruction is the same for every token unless method is overridden.
            foreach (var instruction in Tokens)
            {
                ExecuteOnce(context);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{GetType().Name} x{Tokens.Count()}";
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### ExecutionContext

The interpreter needs a *context* to work with:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace BrainFuck
{
    public class ExecutionContext
    {
        public ExecutionContext(int memorySize = short.MaxValue, Func<int> onInput = null)
        {
            _onInput = onInput;
            _memory = new int[memorySize];
            _stdOutput = new StringBuilder();
        }

        private readonly int[] _memory;
        private readonly Func<int> _onInput;
        private readonly StringBuilder _stdOutput;

        private int _pointer;
        public int Pointer => _pointer;

        public int Value => _memory[_pointer];

        public string StdOut => _stdOutput.ToString();

        public bool IsTrue(int position = -1)
        {
            return (position == -1 ? _memory[_pointer] : _memory[position]) != 0;
        }

        public void MoveLeft()
        {
            if (_pointer == 0)
            {
                _pointer = _memory.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                _pointer--;
            }
        }

        public void MoveRight()
        {
            if (_pointer == _memory.Length)
            {
                _pointer = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _pointer++;
            }
        }

        public void Increment()
        {
            _memory[_pointer] += 1;
        }

        public void Decrement()
        {
            _memory[_pointer] -= 1;
        }

        public void Output()
        {
            _stdOutput.Append((char)_memory[_pointer]);
        }

        public void Input()
        {
            _memory[_pointer] = _onInput?.Invoke() ?? Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I would include the `Token` class as well, but I think this post is long enough already. The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/retailcoder/BrainFuck/tree/b164b85c3743ad51f12ef602aab96d6631de655a) if you need additional context.

So, how's my first real C# 6.0 program?

Comment: Finally upgraded to C#6, eh?

Comment: Finally upgraded from VBA to Brainfuck, eh?

Comment: @SimonForsberg lol, interpreting BrainFuck is mere *practice* for (soon) interpreting VBA code haha

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Additional C#6.0 Modifications

How C#6.0 would you like it to be? You still have a few places you can use more C#6.0:

I'm going to work bottom-to-top in your post:

---

Usually, I don't support using expression-bodied members on `void` methods, but this class would benefit from a few of them:

```
public class ExecutionContext
{
    public ExecutionContext(int memorySize = short.MaxValue, Func<int> onInput = null)
    {
        _onInput = onInput;
        _memory = new int[memorySize];
        _stdOutput = new StringBuilder();
    }

    private readonly int[] _memory;
    private readonly Func<int> _onInput;
    private readonly StringBuilder _stdOutput;

    private int _pointer;
    public int Pointer => _pointer;

    public int Value => _memory[_pointer];

    public string StdOut => _stdOutput.ToString();

    public bool IsTrue(int position = -1)
    {
        return (position == -1 ? _memory[_pointer] : _memory[position]) != 0;
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        if (_pointer == 0)
        {
            _pointer = _memory.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            _pointer--;
        }
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        if (_pointer == _memory.Length)
        {
            _pointer = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _pointer++;
        }
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        _memory[_pointer] += 1;
    }

    public void Decrement()
    {
        _memory[_pointer] -= 1;
    }

    public void Output()
    {
        _stdOutput.Append((char)_memory[_pointer]);
    }

    public void Input()
    {
        _memory[_pointer] = _onInput?.Invoke() ?? Console.Read();
    }
}
```

We'll start with:

```
public void Increment()
{
    _memory[_pointer] += 1;
}

public void Decrement()
{
    _memory[_pointer] -= 1;
}
```

As:

```
public void Increment() => _memory[_pointer]++;
public void Decrement() => _memory[_pointer]--;
```

Sidebar: I don't see a need for a `private` field here:

```
private int _pointer;
public int Pointer => _pointer;
```

Why not just use a property with a `private` setter?

We can do two things with this one:

```
public bool IsTrue(int position = -1)
{
    return (position == -1 ? _memory[_pointer] : _memory[position]) != 0;
}
```

First, replace the `return` with:

```
return _memory[position == -1 ? _pointer : position] != 0;
```

Then, expression-body member that thing:

```
public bool IsTrue(int position = -1) => _memory[position == -1 ? _pointer : position] != 0;
```

But, the next question is, why are you using `-1` as a special case? Make it nullable and we can do one more thing with it:

```
public bool IsTrue(int? position = null) => _memory[position ?? _pointer] != 0;
```

Nice and short.

---

Next, we'll look at:

```
public abstract class InstructionSyntaxTree : SyntaxTree, IInstruction
{
    protected abstract void ExecuteOnce(ExecutionContext context);

    public virtual void Execute(ExecutionContext context)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedVariable; instruction is the same for every token unless method is overridden.
        foreach (var instruction in Tokens)
        {
            ExecuteOnce(context);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{GetType().Name} x{Tokens.Count()}";
    }
}
```

You can make `ToString()` use expression-bodied members:

```
public override string ToString() => $"{GetType().Name} x{Tokens.Count()}";
```

---

There's one potential problem with this, and we can make it more C#6.0 at the same time, what happens if `context` is `null`?

```
public sealed class IncrementInstructionSyntax : InstructionSyntaxTree
{
    protected override void ExecuteOnce(ExecutionContext context)
    {
        context.Increment();
    }
}
```

Well, we can fix that with `?.` (as I assume you know):

```
protected override void ExecuteOnce(ExecutionContext context) => context?.Increment();
```

---

The last thing I want to look at is the `Dictionary`, you can now use the new C#6.0 dictionary initializer syntax instead of the following:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<TokenType, Func<SyntaxTree>> SyntaxTrees =
    new Dictionary<TokenType, Func<SyntaxTree>>
    {
        {TokenType.Trivia, () => new TriviaSyntax()},
        {TokenType.Increment, () => new IncrementInstructionSyntax()},
        {TokenType.Decrement, () => new DecrementInstructionSyntax()},
        {TokenType.MoveLeft, () => new MoveLeftInstructionSyntax()},
        {TokenType.MoveRight, () => new MoveRightInstructionSyntax()},
        {TokenType.Input, () => new InputInstructionSyntax()},
        {TokenType.Output, () => new OutputInstructionSyntax()},
    };
```

Instead of that ugliness, we have a new *slightly* less ugliness:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<TokenType, Func<SyntaxTree>> SyntaxTrees =
    new Dictionary<TokenType, Func<SyntaxTree>>
    {
        [TokenType.Trivia] = () => new TriviaSyntax(),
        [TokenType.Increment] = () => new IncrementInstructionSyntax(),
        [TokenType.Decrement] = () => new DecrementInstructionSyntax(),
        [TokenType.MoveLeft] = () => new MoveLeftInstructionSyntax(),
        [TokenType.MoveRight] = () => new MoveRightInstructionSyntax(),
        [TokenType.Input] = () => new InputInstructionSyntax(),
        [TokenType.Output] = () => new OutputInstructionSyntax(),
    };
```

Instead of `{key, value}` we can use `[key] = value`, which seems to make a little more sense. (It's still a bit ugly to read when the value is a `Func`, but it's still a bit clearer.

---

Next, you used `readonly` on your `IDictionary` and whatnot, but that only blocks *reassignment*. Consumers can still call `.Add` and `.Remove` on them. The easiest way to fix that is to make the `readonly field` a `readonly property` by replacing `=` with `=>`.

---

### Experimental (C#7.0) Modifications

Now I want to talk about how C#7.0 will improve your code, since it's in RC mode right now.

First and foremost I think my favourite feature of C#7.0 is the new way `out` parameters are handled. In C#6.0 my favourite feature was expression-bodied members, and this has the same idea to it: shortening and simplifying code.

Let's take a look at how C#7.0 changes this. In your code (C#6.0) you have the following:

```
Token token;
if (IsToken(currentTokenPosition, tokenCount, current, out token))
```

Now this is what we've been doing since `out` parameters were introduced, because *this was all we had*. Enter C#7.0. Instead of having to declare `token` **before** we use it, we can declare it **as** we use it:

```
if (IsToken(currentTokenPosition, tokenCount, current, out Token token))
```

Now `token` is in scope inside our `if` statement, as we would expect. *As of this writing* `token` is out-of-scope outside the `if` statement, it's unclear if that will be adjusted before final release. (Personally, I like it as it is.)

The same thing here:

```
Func<Span, int, Token> factory;
if (TokenFactories.TryGetValue(input.ToString(), out factory))
```

That simply becomes

```
if (TokenFactories.TryGetValue(input.ToString(), out Func<Span, int, Token> factory))
```

Pretty nifty, and much simpler.

---

The next C#7.0 feature to talk about is local functions. These are declared *inside another function* with the same regular function syntax. I'm not sure what Microsoft's recommendation on using them will be, but I would suggest you could put that entire `IsToken` function *inside* the `Tokenize` function. Syntax is as follows:

```
public string SomeFunction(int parameter)
{
    string localFunction(int someParameter)
    {
        return string.Format("0", someParameter);
    }

    return localFunction(parameter);
}
```

Obviously not particularly *useful* in this case, but you can see how you could move `IsToken` to be a function in `Tokenize`. (Not that it's recommended, just that it's **possible**.)

---

C#7.0 added support for expression-bodied exceptions:

```
protected override void ExecuteOnce(ExecutionContext context)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Can simply be:

```
protected override void ExecuteOnce(ExecutionContext context) => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

The other new features (that I've experimented with so far) are not really all that handy to you, so I'll not describe them.

---

### Conclusion

This is all I can manage to look at when it's 0130 in the morning, but I *hope* it finds you well and you don't hate me for pointing out things I'm sure you already know.

Comment: -1 not enough c#6.0 (just kidding, this is great)

Comment: I think I'm liking C# 6 more and more.

Answer (score 2):

The static `BrainFuck.Parser.Parse` method could use a bit of abstraction.

By extracting a simple overloaded method:

```
private static void AddIfNotNull(SyntaxTree tree, Token token)
{
    tree?.Add(token);
}

private static void AddIfNotNull(SyntaxTree root, SyntaxTree tree)
{
    if (tree != null)
    {
        root.Add(tree);
    }
}
```

And now with just a few more comments the body of the `while` loop becomes crystal-clear, with all the null-checking boilerplate gone:

```
private static SyntaxTree Parse(IReadOnlyList<Token> tokens, ref int index, ref int depth, SyntaxTree parent = null)
{
    if(parent == null) { parent = new SyntaxTree(); }

    Token previousToken = null;
    SyntaxTree currentTree = null;
    SyntaxTree previousTree = null;

    while(index < tokens.Count)
    {
        var token = tokens[index];
        index++;

        Func<SyntaxTree> treeFactory;
        if(SyntaxTrees.TryGetValue(token.Type, out treeFactory))
        {
            // trivia or instruction token
            if(previousToken?.Type == token.Type)
            {
                // same token as before, add to previous tree:
                AddIfNotNull(previousTree, token);
            }
            else
            {
                // new token, add previous tree to root and get a new tree:
                AddIfNotNull(parent, previousTree);

                currentTree = treeFactory.Invoke();
                AddIfNotNull(currentTree, token);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // new control flow token, add previous tree to root:
            AddIfNotNull(parent, previousTree);

            switch(token.Type)
            {
                case TokenType.BeginLoop:
                    depth++;
                    // note: recursive
                    currentTree = Parse(tokens, ref index, ref depth, new LoopBlockSyntax { token });
                    break;

                case TokenType.EndLoop:
                    if(depth == 0) { throw new IllegalTokenException(token); }
                    depth--;

                    AddIfNotNull(parent, token);
                    return parent;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalTokenException(token);
            }
        }

        previousToken = token;
        previousTree = currentTree;
    }

    AddIfNotNull(parent, previousTree);
    return parent;
}
```

Because of the recursive handling of the `BeginLoop` token, the name `root` for the optional parameter isn't ideal; `parent` is a better term, for the actual root is the parent only at depth 0.

---

The `LoopBlockSyntax` is stepping on toes here:

> ```
> private const int MaxIterations = short.MaxValue;
> ```

Instead of this:

> ```
> if (iterations == MaxIterations) { throw new InfiniteLoopException(); }
> ```

You could do this:

```
if (iterations == context.Size) { throw new InfiniteLoopException(); }
```

By simply adding a `Size` property to the `ExecutionContext`:

> ```
> public int Size => _memory.Length;
> ```

That way the loop is sure to be able traverse the entire tape... an arbitrary limitation, really - but just like `_memory.Length` anyway.