# Tokenizer building blocks: tokens and spans

Tags: c#, object-oriented, parsing

In [*a completely overkill BrainFuck lexer/parser*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145060/23788) I've presented the lexer, parser, interpreter and syntax tree classes. With this post I'd like to go over the lower-level `Token` and `Span` mechanics.

Each token has a `Type` property that returns a `TokenType` enum value:

```
namespace BrainFuck.Tokens
{
    public enum TokenType
    {
        Trivia,
        MoveLeft,
        MoveRight,
        BeginLoop,
        EndLoop,
        Increment,
        Decrement,
        Input,
        Output,
    }
}
```

A `Token` represents one or more characters in the BrainFuck source code input; BF lexer makes the `TriviaToken` the only token that can actually span more than a single character, but all tokens have the possibility of being represented with multiple characters. Here's the `Token` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BrainFuck.Tokens
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A base class for all language tokens.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class Token : IEquatable<Token>, IComparable<Token>
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<TokenType, string> Tokens =
            new Dictionary<TokenType, string>
        {
            [TokenType.MoveLeft] = MoveLeftToken.Token,
            [TokenType.MoveRight] = MoveRightToken.Token,
            [TokenType.BeginLoop] = BeginLoopToken.Token,
            [TokenType.EndLoop] = EndLoopToken.Token,
            [TokenType.Increment] = IncrementToken.Token,
            [TokenType.Decrement] = DecrementToken.Token,
            [TokenType.Input] = InputToken.Token,
            [TokenType.Output] = OutputToken.Token,
        };

        protected Token(Span position, int index, TokenType type)
            : this(position, index, Tokens[type])
        {
            Type = type;
        }

        protected Token(Span position, int index, string text)
        {
            Index = index;
            Type = TokenType.Trivia;
            Position = position;
            Text = text;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The type of token.
        /// </summary>
        public TokenType Type { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The position of the token in the source text.
        /// </summary>
        public Span Position { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The position of the token in the token stream.
        /// </summary>
        public int Index { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The text content of the token.
        /// </summary>
        public string Text { get; }

        public bool Equals(Token other)
        {
            return other != null
                && other.Type == Type
                && other.Position == Position
                && other.Text == Text;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Token other)
        {
            if (other == null)
            {
                return Position.CompareTo(Span.Empty);
            }

            return Position.CompareTo(other.Position);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
```

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A trivia token, representing any non-code content.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class TriviaToken : Token
    {
        public TriviaToken(Span position, int index, string text)  : base(position, index, text) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A language token representing a "Move Left" instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class MoveLeftToken : Token
    {
        public static string Token => "<";
        public MoveLeftToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.MoveLeft) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A language token representing a "Move Right" instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class MoveRightToken : Token
    {
        public static string Token => ">";
        public MoveRightToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.MoveRight) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A language token representing a "Begin Loop" instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class BeginLoopToken : Token
    {
        public static string Token => "[";
        public BeginLoopToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.BeginLoop) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A language token representing an "End Loop" instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class EndLoopToken : Token
    {
        public static string Token => "]";
        public EndLoopToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.EndLoop) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A language token representing an "Increment" instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class IncrementToken : Token
    {
        public static string Token => "+";
        public IncrementToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.Increment) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A language token representing a "Decrement" instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class DecrementToken : Token
    {
        public static string Token => "-";
        public DecrementToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.Decrement) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A language token representing an "Input" instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class InputToken : Token
    {
        public static string Token => ",";
        public InputToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.Input) { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A language token representing an "Output" instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class OutputToken : Token
    {
        public static string Token => ".";
        public OutputToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.Output) { }
    }
}
```

The position of a token in the source code input is stored in a `Span` value type which is really nothing more than a `StartLine`, `StartColumn`, `EndLine` and `EndColumn` values and a number of `static` utility methods:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace BrainFuck.Tokens
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A value representing a span of characters in a document.
    /// </summary>
    public struct Span : IEquatable<Span>, IComparable<Span>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an empty span starting and ending at column 0 of line 0.
        /// </summary>
        public static Span Empty => new Span();

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a single-character span at specified line and column.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="line">The start/end document line.</param>
        /// <param name="column">The start/end document column.</param>
        public Span(int line, int column) : this(line, column, line, column) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a span within the specified document coordinates.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startLine">The starting document line.</param>
        /// <param name="startColumn">The starting document column.</param>
        /// <param name="endLine">The ending document line.</param>
        /// <param name="endColumn">The ending document column.</param>
        public Span(int startLine, int startColumn, int endLine, int endColumn)
        {
            StartLine = startLine;
            EndLine = endLine;
            StartColumn = startColumn;
            EndColumn = endColumn;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The starting line position.
        /// </summary>
        public int StartLine { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The ending line position.
        /// </summary>
        public int EndLine { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The starting column position.
        /// </summary>
        public int StartColumn { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The ending column position.
        /// </summary>
        public int EndColumn { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of lines in the document coordinates.
        /// </summary>
        public int Lines => EndLine - StartLine + 1;

        /// <summary>
        /// Extends the span to the next line. Returns a new Span with the same start position, ending on next line at column 0.
        /// </summary>
        public Span NextLine => new Span(StartLine, StartColumn, EndLine + 1, 0);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a new span starting on the next line, at column 0
        /// </summary>
        public Span NewLine => new Span(EndLine + 1, 0, EndLine + 1, 0);

        /// <summary>
        /// Extends the span to the next column. Returns a new Span with the same start position, ending on the same line at the next column.
        /// </summary>
        public Span NextColumn => new Span(StartLine, StartColumn, EndLine, EndColumn + 1);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a new span starting on the same line, at the next column.
        /// </summary>
        public Span Next => new Span(EndLine, EndColumn + 1);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a new span with the same start position, ending on the same line at the previous column.
        /// </summary>
        public Span PreviousColumn => new Span(StartLine, StartColumn, EndLine, EndColumn - 1);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a new span starting at the end of the current position.
        /// </summary>
        public Span End => new Span(EndLine, EndColumn);

        public Span OffSet(int columns, int lines = 0)
        {
            return new Span(StartLine + lines, StartColumn + columns, EndLine + lines, EndColumn + columns);
        }

        public Span Combine(Span other)
        {
            return Combine(this, other);
        }

        public static Span Combine(params Span[] a)
        {
            var min = a.Min();
            var max = a.Max();
            return new Span(min.StartLine, min.StartColumn, max.EndLine, max.EndColumn);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Span x, Span y)
        {
            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Span x, Span y)
        {
            return !x.Equals(y);
        }

        public bool Equals(Span other)
        {
            return other.StartLine == StartLine
                   && other.EndLine == EndLine
                   && other.StartColumn == StartColumn
                   && other.EndColumn == EndColumn;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Span other)
        {
            if (Equals(other))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (other.StartLine < StartLine || (other.StartLine == StartLine && other.StartColumn < StartColumn))
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return 1;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj != null && Equals((Span)obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Compute(StartLine, EndLine, StartColumn, EndColumn);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Lines == 1
                ? $"L{EndLine}C{EndColumn}"
                : $"L{StartLine}C{StartColumn}:L{EndLine}C{EndColumn}";
        }
    }
}
```

These utility methods are very useful for cleanly generating tokens when writing unit tests:

> ```
> [TestMethod]
> public void GivenConsecutiveInstructions_RegroupsSyntaxTreeByTokenType()
> {
>     var parser = new Parser();
>     var tree = parser.Parse(new Token[]
>     {
>         new IncrementToken(Span.Empty.OffSet(0), 0),
>         new IncrementToken(Span.Empty.OffSet(1), 1),
>         new DecrementToken(Span.Empty.OffSet(2), 2),
>         new DecrementToken(Span.Empty.OffSet(3), 3),
>     });
>
>     Assert.AreEqual(2, tree.Children.Count());
> }
> ```

The `Lexer` class also makes good use of them. I tried to come up with a little naming scheme, but found that XML comments would be the most efficient way to convey exactly what a method is returning. Or would there be better names for them? Also, do `Equals` and `CompareTo` implementations look right? Any other feedback is welcome, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking at your code thinking "it's so nice to see struct when it makes sense and one that implements all the equality and comparison stuff!". Then I saw this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)  
{
     return obj != null && Equals((Span)obj);
}
```

And I broke down and wept.

I give you the following test case:

```
Span.Empty.Equals(new object());
// InvalidCastException
```

You can fix it with the `as` dance:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)  
{
    var otherSpan = obj as Span?;
    return otherSpan != null && Equals(otherSpan.Value);
}
```

Or with `is` which I actually prefer in this case from a readability point of view:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)  
{
     return obj is Span && Equals((Span)obj);
}
```

Other than that, nothing is jumping out at me.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at three of your token classes:

```
/// <summary>
/// A language token representing a "Move Left" instruction.
/// </summary>
public sealed class MoveLeftToken : Token
{
    public static string Token => "<";
    public MoveLeftToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.MoveLeft) { }
}

/// <summary>
/// A language token representing a "Move Right" instruction.
/// </summary>
public sealed class MoveRightToken : Token
{
    public static string Token => ">";
    public MoveRightToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.MoveRight) { }
}

/// <summary>
/// A language token representing a "Begin Loop" instruction.
/// </summary>
public sealed class BeginLoopToken : Token
{
    public static string Token => "[";
    public BeginLoopToken(Span position, int index) : base(position, index, TokenType.BeginLoop) { }
}
```

Now let me ask you: Did you copy-paste any code while writing this? You did, didn't you?

I don't see a reason for why you need 8 (one for each BF instruction) different *classes*. How about 8 different *objects* instead? Or 8 different *factory methods* possibly. You are not using any OOP aspects for these token classes. So.... do they really deserve to be classes?

Forgive my Java, but may I suggest something like this instead?

```
public class Tokens {
    public static final String TOKEN_INCREMENT = "+";

    public static Token increment(Span position, int index) {
        return new Token(position, index, TOKEN_INCREMENT);
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, there is no functionality that you would lose out on if you would go this way instead.

Comment: Java forgiven =)

Comment: I like how this solves the very annoying problem I was having with these repeated `public static string Token` members. But no, I don't recall Copy+Pasting anything here. R# Alt+Enter to auto-implement a constructor doesn't count, does it?